# AS3 XMLListCollection removing elements from source XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm working with an XMLListCollection in AS3 and I've run into what I feel is weird behavior and I'm not sure if I'm just misunderstanding how it's suppose to work. I have this code set up in a project:

```
var xml:XML = <root><child /><child /></root>;

var childs:XMLList = xml.child;
var newChilds:XMLList = new XMLList();
var childListCol:XMLListCollection;

for each (var childXml:XML in childs) 
{
    newChilds += childXml;
}

childListCol = new XMLListCollection(newChilds);

childListCol.removeAll();
```

After the last line gets run, the child nodes are also removed from the original xml variable so that xml then looks like this:

```
<root></root>
```

Is this the expected behavior of removeAll() in this instance?